# why my data is not shown?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-listview

I am trying to retrieve data from a db. I don't get any error, but the data is not shown.
Here is my code:

DbHelper

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

static final String tag="dbHelper";

static final String DB_NAME="dianaaaa.db";
static final int DB_VERSION=1;
static final String TABLE_JOBS="jobs";
static final String C_START="start";
static final String C_STOP="stop";
static final String C_ID_J=BaseColumns._ID;
Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;



public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

String sql2="create table "+TABLE_JOBS+"( "+C_ID_J+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+C_START+" text, "+C_STOP+" text)";

    try{
        db.execSQL(sql2);   
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        Log.d(tag, "no");
    }finally{

    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+TABLE_JOBS);
    Log.d(tag, "onUpdated");
    onCreate(db);

}


public void insertJStart(String s1){
    SQLiteDatabase db = (SQLiteDatabase) getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.clear();
    values.put(DbHelper.C_START, s1);
    try{


    db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_JOBS, C_START, values);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        Log.d(tag, "nu vreau....");

    }finally{

    db.close();
    }
}

public void insertJStop(String s2){
    SQLiteDatabase db=(SQLiteDatabase) getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.clear();
    values.put(DbHelper.C_STOP, s2);
    db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_JOBS, C_STOP, values);

    db.close();
}


public Cursor getCursor(){
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_JOBS);

    String[] asColumToRetrun=new String[] { C_ID, C_START, C_STOP};


    Cursor mCursor=db.query(TABLE_JOBS, asColumToRetrun, null, null, null, null, "time ASC");

    return mCursor;
}

public String getDate(Cursor c, int i){

    return (c.getString(i));
}




public Cursor getAll(){

    db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jobs ", new String[]{});
    return c;
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class TimerDB extends Activity{

static final String tag="TimerDB";

private ListView list;
MyAdapter aa=null;
private Cursor cursor=null;
private DbHelper helper=null;

final ArrayList<String> aList=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.times);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.timeList);

    helper=new DbHelper(this);
    cursor=helper.getAll();
    cursor.moveToNext();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    aa=new MyAdapter(cursor);
    list.setAdapter(aa);

}

class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    MyAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(TimerDB.this, c);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row=convertView;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        return (row);

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=(Holder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);

        c.moveToNext();

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        Holder holder=new Holder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }   
}

static class Holder {
    private TextView id, start, stop;   

    Holder(View row){
        id=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowViewStart);
        start=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowViewStart);
        stop=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowViewStop);
    }
    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DbHelper db){
        id.setText(db.getDate(c, 0));
        start.setText(db.getDate(c, 1));
        stop.setText(db.getDate(c, 2));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have any data in the DB? I could not find a code (in TimerDB activity) which inserts a data into the your DB.

Comment: yes, I have another activity where I insert the data
is something like this:
 bStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
   
    dbhelp.insertJStart(clock.getText().toString());

    
    Log.d(tag, "StartButton");
    
   }
  });

Comment: @DianaC Does your list show empty rows?

Comment: yes, you know which could be the problem?

Comment: I think that you should populate your row in the getView() method.

Comment: i don't have a getView() method anymore. I only kept bindView(). I can't edit my post, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom adapter you either implement the `getView()` method or you implement `newView()` and the `bindView()` method(but not together with `getView()`). Right now you implement those two methods but also `override` `getView()` and you "cover" your adapter implementation from those methods. Simply leave the `newView()` and `bindView()` and remove the `getView()` method.

If you look at the android source code, in the case of cursor adapters the `getView()` method delegates the row creation to those methods(it is calling `newView()` for a `View` object and then `bindView()` to bind the data from the cursor).

Edit:

-Also don't call `c.moveToNext();`, the `Cursor` will always be positioned correctly.

Comment: I commented all getView() function and is the same... still empty rows

Comment: @DianaC Could you also add the layout for the list row `R.layout.row`?

Comment: this is what I get when I edit my own post: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: @DianaC I don't know why does that happen. Put your code on http://pastebin.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: @DianaC Have you tested `clock.getText().toString()` if it isn't a empty `String`? I've tested your code and it works.

Comment: i did debug it, and it shows me that is not null (empty) ...strange...thank you for trying :)

Comment: @DianaC http://pastebin.com/U6nrmM76 this code works, see maybe you've missed something.